# How to use Google to find current location, without asking for permission

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I just did a Google search using: 'get current location' and I got this result:

[image]

It didn't ask me for my location, so I guess it's based on the IP location, or perhaps a cross reference of several information coming from my network (logged Google Accounts, Mobile devices, etc).

Is there a way to use Google Maps API, or any related Google service, to get this information, without having to ask the user for permission on the browser, to get their location?

Thank you

Comment: People voting negative this question: would you mind explaining what's wrong with it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a part of the Maps-API, but you may use the JSAPI(e.g. load the Maps-API via the JSAPI).

Although it isn't officially supported anymore, there still is(but must not be set) a property `google.loader.ClientLocation`

```js
  google.load("maps", "3",{callback:function() {
        try{
          opts={
                center:new google.maps.LatLng( google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude,
                                               google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude),
                zoom:8
               };
        }catch(e){alert('no location available');
          opts={
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                zoom: 0
               };
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            opts);
      }
      });
```

```css
html,body,#map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Of course it's only as accurate as IP-based geolocation may be...not much